# Can anyone give me a quick tutorial in stdin and stdout in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout, stdin

I know this sounds like something I can google, but the truth is that I don't find or do not understand what the very few Python 3 sources explains.

So here are my questions:

- Is `input()` the `stdin` function in Python 3? Does that mean that when you open your filename.py program, the `stdin` is what the user types?
- Is `print()` the `stdout` function in Python 3, or do you have to write to a file?
- For the **[Spotify puzzle](http://www.spotify.com/us/jobs/tech/best-before/)**, is says "Input is read from stdin". What should my file include of `stdin` and `stdout`?

---

Update:
Does that mean that i can use:

```
import sys
unfmtdDate = str(sys.stdin.read())
```

...instead of...

```
unfmtdDate = str(input())
```

?

Comment: What do you mean by 'stdin function' and 'stout function'?  Stdin and stout are files.  Not functions.  These files have methods for reading or writing.  Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I mean how do you write to the files, and is it possible to look at those files?

Comment: The answers are: 1. "Yes and yes".  2. "Yes". 3. "Huh? That question makes no sense." Update: "Yes, and no."

Comment: "Does that mean that i can use...?"  When you tried it, what did you observe?

Comment: It says i can't use the read() function, even though several guys here told me i could. It would also be impossible to test my program, since it wont promt

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`stdin` and `stdout` are file-like objects provided by the OS. In general, when a program is run in an interactive session, `stdin` is keyboard input and `stdout` is the user's tty, but the shell can be used to redirect them from normal files or piped output from and input to other programs.

`input()` is used to prompt the user for typed input. In the case of something like a programming puzzle, it's normally assumed that `stdin` is redirected from a data file, and when the input format is given it's usually best to use `sys.stdin.read()` rather than prompting for input with `input()`.  `input()` is intended for interactive user input, it can display a prompt (on sys.stdout) and use the GNU readline library (if present) to allow line editing, etc.

`print()` is, indeed, the most common way of writing to `stdout`. There's no need to do anything special to specify the output stream.  `print()` writes to `sys.stdout` if no alternate file is given to it as a `file=` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

When you run your Python program, [`sys.stdin`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) is the file object connected to standard input (STDIN), `sys.stdout` is the file object for standard output (STDOUT), and `sys.stderr` is the file object for standard error (STDERR).

Anywhere in the documentation you see references to standard input, standard output, or standard error, it is referring to these file handles.  You can access them directly (`sys.stdout.write(...)`, `sys.stdin.read()` etc.) or use convenience functions that use these streams, like `input()` and `print()`.

For the Spotify puzzle, the easiest way to read the input would be something like this:

```
import sys
data = sys.stdin.read()
```

After these two lines the input for your program is now in the str `data`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is `input()` the `stdin` function in Python 3?

Yes.

> Does that mean that when you open your `filename.py` program, the `stdin` is what the user types?

Yes.

> Is `print()` the `stdout` function in Python 3, or do you have to write to a file?

You can use either.

> For the Spotify puzzle, is says "Input is read from stdin". What should my file include of `stdin` and `stdout`?

Just use `import sys` to get to the `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` files. You don't need the import if you use the `input` and `print` built-in functions instead.

Comment: `stout`? `stein`? Have another beer!

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: My browser seems to have grown itself an autocorrect future. It's being annoying.

Answer (score 1):

> Is input() the stdin function in Python 3? Does that mean that when you open your filename.py program, the stdin is what the user types?

`input()` reads from the standard input (called `stdin` for short in some contexts), yes. No language that I know of has a **function** named `stdin` in the standard library. When you run the program in the usual way, what the user types is supplied to standard input, yes. That's what "standard input" means. There is a separate program that is feeding what the user types to standard input (and doing a couple of other convenient things like interpreting the backspace key). Your script **is not what creates the window** that text is typed into.

`sys.stdin` (i.e., the value `stdin` defined in the `sys` module) is an **object** that **represents** the standard input. This is provided so that you can use it in contexts where you're expected to specify "a file", to cause input to be read from the user instead of a file.

> Is print() the stdout function in Python 3, or do you have to write to a file?

`print()` writes (by default; you can supply a `file` keyword argument to change this) to the standard output (called `stdout` for short in some contexts), yes. All the above caveats apply: `stdout` isn't a function in any language I've ever heard of, and a completely separate program is actually causing the output of your script to be displayed on screen in a pretty 80x24 white-text-on-black-background (or however you have it configured) box.

`sys.stdout` is an **object** that **represents** the standard output, used similarly to `sys.stdin`. You can use it explicitly with the `print` function, but there's no point: it's the default.

> For the Spotify puzzle, is says "Input is read from stdin". What should my file include of stdin and stdout?

The problem specification means "use the `input()` function to receive input".

Comment: Note that `input()` **cannot** read from a specified file (there are ways to cause the standard input to be a file, but again, that's generally external to your program). It's not meant to be exactly symmetric with the `print()` function. After all, it displays a prompt... wouldn't make sense to display a prompt while reading from a file, see?

Answer (score 0):

From [the Python documentation for `print`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#print):

> The *file* argument must be an object with a `write(string)` method; if it is not present or `None`, `sys.stdout` will be used. Output buffering is determined by *file*. Use `file.flush()` to ensure, for instance, immediate appearance on a screen.