# Codeforces not accepting my output even though it looks exactly the same?

Tags: python, int

I am trying to complete a low level question on codeforces but even though my solution passes the tests, it still registers as an error. It keeps saying that "wrong output format Unexpected end of file - int32 expected". What does this mean? Question can be found at https://codeforces.com/contest/1154/problem/A

```
#a+b = w
#a+c = x
#b+c = y
#a+b+c = z
def restore_numbers(w,x,y,z):
    biggest = max(w,y,z,x)
    if biggest - w > 0:
        num = biggest-w
    else:
        num = biggest
    if biggest - x > 0:
        num1 = biggest-x
    else:
        num1 = biggest
    if biggest -y > 0:
        num2 = biggest-y
    else:
        num2 = biggest
    if biggest - z > 0:
        num3 = biggest-z
    else:
        num3 = biggest-z
    arr = [num,num1,num2,num3]
    arr.sort()
    arr = arr[0:3]
    s = [str(i) for i in arr]
    res = (" ".join(s))
    return res 
print(restore_numbers(3,6,5,4))
```

What should happen is that I solve all the tests but this does not happen.

Comment: Can't help without knowing what the question is.

Comment: https://codeforces.com/contest/1154/problem/A

Comment: If this is your submission (https://codeforces.com/contest/1154/submission/53100640) then you need to read the values from the stdin.

Comment: What is a stdin?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980520. You can also look at other contestants' submissions to take some inspiration (spoilers: https://codeforces.com/contest/1154/submission/53097932)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will be run multiple times under different inputs and so your code must adapt to be able to read various inputs. In order to achieve this you must read from where the input is coming from: `stdin` (standard input)

In python you can use `input()` to read from the `stdin` and then pass in these values into your `restore_numbers(w,x,y,z)`

However, these numbers are all on one line in the input (e.g. `3 6 5 4`) so you can create a `map` that holds `int` and get the input from the one line, and use `split()` to separate the numbers using the default delimiter (space). Then you pass turn it into a `list` and access each number individually to pass into the `restore_numbers(w,x,y,z)` function.

One solution would be:

```
#a+b = w
#a+c = x
#b+c = y
#a+b+c = z
def restore_numbers(w,x,y,z):
  biggest = max(w,y,z,x)
  if biggest - w > 0:
      num = biggest-w
  else:
      num = biggest
  if biggest - x > 0:
      num1 = biggest-x
  else:
      num1 = biggest
  if biggest -y > 0:
      num2 = biggest-y
  else:
      num2 = biggest
  if biggest - z > 0:
      num3 = biggest-z
  else:
      num3 = biggest-z
  arr = [num,num1,num2,num3]
  arr.sort()
  arr = arr[0:3]
  s = [str(i) for i in arr]
  res = (" ".join(s))
  return res
nums = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(restore_numbers(nums[0],nums[1],nums[2],nums[3]))
```

Now the code can be run multiple times across various inputs.